# Beamer like Sidebar in Article

Tags: xetex, article

I would like insert a sidebar (colored with text) on certain page. I searched for a while but couldn't find anything.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=25mm,
    right=40mm,
    top=40mm,
    bottom=25mm,
}

\usepackage{boxedminipage}

% turn off indentation
\usepackage{parskip}

% german spelling
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% set font encoding                                                                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}                                                               

% set fonts                                                                        
\usepackage{xltxtra}                                                               

%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}                                                   
\setsansfont[                                                                      
BoldFont={Helvetica Neue Medium},                                                  
ItalicFont={Helvetica Neue Italic},                                             
BoldItalicFont={Helvetica Neue Medium Italic},                                  
Ligatures=TeX                                                                   
]{Helvetica Neue Light}                                                         

\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Menlo Regular}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

It sould look like this (the text should not be under the side bar ;) )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `scrlayer` to define a new page style for this page(s):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{ 
     a4paper, 
     %total={210mm,297mm}, 
     left=25mm, 
     right=40mm, 
     top=40mm, 
     bottom=25mm, 
} 

\usepackage{boxedminipage} 
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
%\setsansfont[
 %BoldFont={Helvetica Neue Medium},
 %ItalicFont={Helvetica Neue Italic},
 %BoldItalicFont={Helvetica Neue Medium Italic},
 %Ligatures=TeX
%]{Helvetica Neue Light}
%\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Menlo Regular} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  outermargin,
  addhoffset=\marginparsep,
  contents={\color{blue!20}\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}
]{sidebar.bg}
\makeatletter
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=sidebar.bg,
  addhoffset=1em,
  addwidth=-1em,
  contents={\parbox[b][\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\raggedright\@sidebar}}
]{sidebar.txt}
\newcommand\@sidebar{}
\newcommand\sidebar[1]{\renewcommand\@sidebar{#1}}
\makeatother
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{sidebar}{sidebar.bg,sidebar.txt}

\usepackage{blindtext} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document} 
\newgeometry{right=5cm}
\thispagestyle{sidebar}
\sidebar{%
  \vspace{1em}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.pdf}\par
  \vspace{1cm}
  \pagename~\pagemark
  \vfill
  Hier steht noch etwas anderes
  \par\vspace*{1em}
}
\blindtext
\cleardoublepage
\restoregeometry
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that it is still possible to use `fancyhdr` for the page styles on the other pages.