# Table of Contents navigation sidebar in non-beamer document classes

Tags: pdftex, article

I am trying to create a sidebar like the one present in beamer documents, which lists the Table of Contents information for easy document navigation. Even better if it can automatically show only the subsections for the current section. How can this be implemented in other LaTeX classes, such as the article class, for use with pdflatex? [This page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254473/beamer-like-sidebar-in-article) has a suggestion but it does not work in pdflatex.

Comment: please help us by adding an example of your code.

Comment: There is no example because I do not know how to implement this. Thus, the question.

Comment: What I mean is that we need to know class, packages used.

Comment: article class would be most convenient but is not essential. I do not know which packages are best suited for this. I am interested in any examples or any suggestions anyone might have on implementing this.

Comment: well i will try to see.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: I ultimately scrapped the whole idea and have been using [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) instead, it now includes a better Table of Contents at the expense of using HTML output format instead of PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using [etoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc/) package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocdepth{2}% only subsection
\etocsettocstyle{}{}% no heading
\etocsetstyle {subsection}
{}
{}
{\etocnumber.\etocname\nobreak\quad\nobreak\etocpage\hfill}
{}

% here with fancyhdr package
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[C]{\tableofcontents \ref{\mt}} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% or with background package
%\usepackage[placement=top,scale=1]{background}
%\backgroundsetup{contents={\tableofcontents \ref{\mt}},color=blue}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\edef\mt{foo}\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{\mt}
\subsection{Foo bar}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Foo baz}
\subsubsection{Foo baz}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Foo Bye}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Baz}
\edef\mt{baz}\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{\mt}
\subsection{Baz bar}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\subsection{Baz baz}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Baz Bye}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**with fancyhdr**
[image]

---

**with background**

[image]